# Applescript won't make Safari open a URL at a new window

Tags: applescript

I'm making a Applescript service that receives selected text and opens a google query with this text. This was the first version of it:

```
on run {input, parameters}
set myBrowser to http://google.com.br?q=" & input as text
set the_url to "Safari" as text

tell application myBrowser
    open location "http://google.com.br?q=" & input
    set the bounds of the front window to {100, 22, 800, 1024}
    activate
end tell
end run
```

This one above works well. The problem came when I tried to make the browser open a new page with the query, instead of a new tab. I had to come up with a solution for it not opening two tabs at the new window, as it would happen when the script is triggered and Safari is closed:

```
on run {input, parameters}
set the_url to "http://google.com.br?q=" & input
set myBrowser to "Safari" as text

set aWindowIsOpen to false
tell application myBrowser
    repeat with thisWindow in windows
        if (not miniaturized of thisWindow) then
            set aWindowIsOpen to true
        end if
    end repeat

    if (aWindowIsOpen) then
        make new document with properties {URL:the_url}
        set the bounds of the front window to {100, 22, 800, 1024}
        activate
    else
        activate
        make new document with properties {URL:the_url}
        set the bounds of the front window to {100, 22, 800, 1024}
        activate
    end if
end tell
end run
```

So the problem now is that the browser won't open the URL. Any thoughs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tell application "Safari"` instead of `tell application myBrowser`.

---

Or, use `using terms from application "Safari"`, like this:

> ```
> set myBrowser to "Safari"
> using terms from application "Safari"
>   tell application myBrowser
>       make new document with properties {URL:the_url}
>   end tell
> end using terms from
> ```

Comment: Amazing, thank you very much! I just added the "activate" command after the make command, if not the window won't pop in front of others.